# Как отобразить элементы html только если значение поля после ввода пользователя удовлетворяет условие (без JS)

Tags: html, css

Подскажите есть ли возможность отобразить элементы на html странице идущие после формы только если введенные данные соответствуют условию? В противном случае будет толко вывод фразы "Wrong input" с помощью CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.true,
.false {
  display: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}

input:valid~.true {
  display: block;
  color: green;
}

input:invalid~.false {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}

input:placeholder-shown~.true {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span>введите несколько цифр:&nbsp;</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="" pattern="\d{1,}">
<div class="true">True</div>
<div class="false">False</div>
```

Comment: а что должно произойти ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, если вводишь цифру - появляется сообщение `true`, а если букву, тогда `false`. А что у вас не работает?

Comment: точно - круто ....